# JTextArea in JScrollPane

Tags: jscrollpane, jtextarea

I want to make JTextArea scrollable...
I have tried following code.. but am not getting why its not working... Pls help !

```
jacontactsDeatil = new JTextArea();  
jspn = new JScrollPane();  
jspn.setLayout(null);  
jspn.setBounds(10, 170, 950, 300);
jspn.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
    jspn.isWheelScrollingEnabled();  
    jspn.setVisible(true);  
    jspn.setAutoscrolls(true);  
    jspn.setEnabled(true);

    jspn.setBackground(Color.orange);  
    jspn.add(jacontactsDetail);
    jspn.repaint();
    jacontactsDetail.setBounds(0,0,jspn.getWidth(),jspn.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the JTextArea and the JScrollPane together with a GroupLayout.

```
jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
jTextArea1.setRows(5);
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().
    addComponent(jScrollPane1,
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 328,
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
);
jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().
    addComponent(jScrollPane1,
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79,
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
);
```

Comment: That worked best ! I am not able to set X,Y axis Alignments to GroupLayout. I used createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(10,170,Short.MAx_Value) .... but its not working. I want X axis to be at 10 and Y at 170.